# Angular AsyncPipe For Multiple Dropdowns Load Once

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have n number of autocompletes in my HTML like this:

```
<mat-form-field style="padding-left: 10px" floatLabel="never">
  <input type="text"
    matInput
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    formControlName="person">
  <mat-label>Search Labor</mat-label>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let person of getAsyncPeople(city) | async [value]="person.personId">
      {{person.personId}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have an async pipe that provides the values for each drop down based on an HTTP call that gets lists of people at different cities. When I run my page I do not get any dropdown values to show up, it also looks like the service gets called constantly. I want the API to return once for each dropdown and not continually get called.

```
getAsyncPeople(city: string): Observable<Person[]> {
  return this.service.getPeople(city).pipe(share())
}
```

Comment: This article may demonstrate your issue: https://blog.strongbrew.io/how-share%28%29-can-reduce-network-requests/

Comment: @DeborahK I am already using share, I also tried publishReplay.

Comment: Can you do a simplified version of your code as a stackblitz so we could see the issue more readily?

Comment: Calling a method in a binding causes the method to be called every time Angular change detection runs. That's why you are seeing the service get called constantly.

Comment: Also, since you are passing in *different* cities each time, I don't think that the share (or publishReplay) handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't have your code to work with, I did the code with users and ToDos:

```
  // Action stream
  private userSelectedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  userSelectedAction$ = this.userSelectedSubject.asObservable();

  // All Users
  users$ = this.http
    .get<User[]>(this.userUrl)
    .pipe(catchError(err => throwError("Error occurred")));

  // Todos for selected user
  // NOTE: shareReplay doesn't work in this case as it is changing
  // for each userId.
  toDos$ = this.userSelectedAction$.pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    switchMap(userId =>
      this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${userId}`)
        .pipe(
          tap(todos => console.log(JSON.stringify(todos))),
          shareReplay(1)
        )
    )
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onSelected(userId): void {
    this.userSelectedSubject.next(userId);
  }
```

The important difference from your code and this code is that the stream is declared (toDos$) instead of being a function call.

You can try out the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-selectedaction-deborahk

This resolves the issue of the service getting called constantly. But it does not resolve the issue of getting the data one time.

For that, would it be possible to literally get all of the people for all of the cities in *one* async call and then filter them as needed? Then the `shareReplay` would retain the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that your quote is at the end of *ngFor property?

```
<mat-form-field style="padding-left: 10px" floatLabel="never">
                  <input type="text"
                         matInput
                         [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                         formControlName="person">
                  <mat-label>Search Labor</mat-label>
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let person of getAsyncPeople(city) | async" [value]="person.personId">
                      {{person.personId}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
```

if not work, I would like to see code of getPeople(city) function, I recommend to use a variable for async
`cityPersons: Observable<any> = new Observable();`

`*ngFor="let person of cityPersons | async"`